# merge a part of array recursive php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I tried googling it but unable to find anything close.
Is it possible to merge two array but actually a part of second array?

These array would be very long and on second I want to just use the categories from second array and merge in first!

My array:

```
$ar1 = array(
    "locale" => "en-US",
    "id" => 1,
    "categories" => array(
        "0" => array("name" => "abc", "username" => "abc1"),
        "1" => array("name" => "cdf", "username" => "bbb3"),
    )
);

$ar2 = array(
    "locale" => "en-US",
    "id" => 1,
    "categories" => array(
        "0" => array("name" => "xyz", "username" => "xyz4"),
        "1" => array("name" => "zyx", "username" => "xtt44"),
    )
);
```

I tried **array_merge**, **array_merge_recursive** but it does not work.

I am getting

```
Array
(
    [locale] => Array
        (
            [0] => en-US
            [1] => en-US
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc
                    [username] => abc1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => cdf
                    [username] => bbb3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => xyz
                    [username] => xyz4
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => zyx
                    [username] => xtt44
                )

        )

)
```

But this is what I want:

```
Array
(
    [locale] => Array
        (
            [0] => en-US
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc
                    [username] => abc1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => cdf
                    [username] => bbb3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => xyz
                    [username] => xyz4
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => zyx
                    [username] => xtt44
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: using `foreach` loop you need to design a new array.

Comment: Can I avoid foreach? There is no other way I can do?

Comment: you have same index in each array, so in every array function you got only one value.

Comment: Yes that is the main problem :(

Comment: Go ahead and continue questioning... also have to the habit of accepting the useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a Built-In Function. Yes; it is just a nested Loop with branched out conditionals.
Test it... and see if (most importantly) it does what you want... the rest is a matter of choice: ***Simplicity over complexity.***

Here are the Given Arrays: **$ar1** and **$ar2**

```
    <?php

        $ar1 = array(
            "locale" => "en-US",
            "id" => 1,
            "categories" => array(
                "0" => array("name" => "abc", "username" => "abc1"),
                "1" => array("name" => "cdf", "username" => "bbb3"),
            )
        );

        $ar2 = array(
            "locale" => "en-US",
            "id" => 1,
            "categories" => array(
                "0" => array("name" => "xyz", "username" => "xyz4"),
                "1" => array("name" => "zyx", "username" => "xtt44"),
            )
        );
```

And here's to the Looping Construct:

```
    <?php

        $arrResult  = array();

        foreach($ar1 as $key=>$value){
            if(!array_key_exists($key, $arrResult)){

                if(is_array($value)){
                    $arrResult[$key] = array();
                    for($i=0; $i<count($value); $i++){
                        $arrResult[$key][] = $value[$i];
                    }
                }else{
                    $arrResult[$key] = $value;
                }

                foreach ($ar2 as $index => $item) {
                    if(!array_key_exists($index, $arrResult)){
                        if(is_array($item)){
                            if($key == $index) {
                                $arrResult[$index] = array();
                                for ($j = 0; $j < count($item); $j++) {
                                    $arrResult[$key][] = $item[$j];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(is_array($item)){
                            if($key == $index) {
                                for ($j = 0; $j < count($item); $j++) {
                                    array_push($arrResult[$index], $item[$j]);
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            $arrResult[$index] = $item;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        var_dump($arrResult);

?>
```

Here is the Output of the var_dump():

```
    array (size=3)
        'locale' => string 'en-US' (length=5)
        'id' => int 1
    'categories' =>
    array (size=4)
        0 =>
        array (size=2)
            'name' => string 'abc' (length=3)
            'username' => string 'abc1' (length=4)
        1 =>
        array (size=2)
            'name' => string 'cdf' (length=3)
            'username' => string 'bbb3' (length=4)
        2 =>
        array (size=2)
            'name' => string 'xyz' (length=3)
            'username' => string 'xyz4' (length=4)
        3 =>
        array (size=2)
            'name' => string 'zyx' (length=3)
            'username' => string 'xtt44' (length=5)
```

I still believe you may need to add your own logic (if you like it) depending on your use-case and preference.

Comment: I tried and this is exactly what I want :). Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-replace.php) or [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-replace-recursive.php). 
Or this function I recently wrote (based on some code found on the internet): https://gist.github.com/jehaby/e91b6d35661ba8900644e5d64cc0055b

Comment: Tried your git function, it replaces my array and send me this: http://prntscr.com/b2trfx
but if I change my key it works for all the functions http://prntscr.com/b2trlw (array_merge, array_merge_recursive)

Answer (score 0):

Either array_combine or using array_merge like this:

```
array_merge($ar1, $ar2['categories']);
```

Comment: Ah yeah sorry I did not see that. Looks like you got a working solution from Stas Makraov though right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use foreach loop here. Because your index's are similar.

```
$result = array();

$result['locale'] = array('en-US');
$result['id'] = array(1);
foreach($ar1['categories'] as $val){
    $result['categories'][] = array('name' => $val['name'], 'username' => $val['username']);
}

foreach($ar2['categories'] as $val){
    $result['categories'][] = array('name' => $val['name'], 'username' => $val['username']);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [locale] => Array
    (
        [0] => en-US
    )

    [id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc
                    [username] => abc1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => cdf
                    [username] => bbb3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => xyz
                    [username] => xyz4
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => zyx
                    [username] => xtt44
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This might be correct, but as I said I have a long list of array and this is just a part. I cannot manually copy the part of the array as you have done using  $result['locale'] = array('en-US');
$result['id'] = array(1);
This will not solve the problem.